# How to integrate Appdynamics in/with Istio?

Tags: integration, istio, envoyproxy, appdynamics, servicemesh

I am new to Istio service mesh. I have to integrate/configure appdynamics in istio. I have no clue how to do that. Anything related to this would help. Any example or related links or video...anything.

Comment: Can you login to the AppyDynamics platform? Because from there you will obtain everything you will need to integrate your service

Comment: Okay. I will try. WIll istio be there? There is so less info about Istio. Btw Thanks!

Comment: Haven't used Istio, but seems to be a tool to deploy & manage your webapp on the cloud, right? If that's the case, then AppDynamics would be needed to track user metrics interactions on your app. What type of product do you need to integrate? Web? Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

From checking out the code for Istio - https://github.com/istio - this appears to be an application with components written in Go and C++ which are deployed to containers using Kubernetes.

This would mean that for monitoring you should be looking at:

- Go SDK - https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/Go+SDK - To instrument Go elements
- C/C++ SDK - https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/CCPP+SDK - To instrument C++ elements
- Cluster Agent - https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/Monitor+Kubernetes+with+the+Cluster+Agent - to monitor the containers

You have you work cut out for you here - both SDK's would require changes to the code being ran to get visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Istio being a service mesh for k8s. You can use AppD Cluster agent for k8s in general.

But if your referring to things like the istio specific metrics, you could leverage the prometheus collector, then use the prometheus/appd extension to pull those specific istio metrics into appd's metric store in the controller. At which point you could do rules against them and get baselines like any metric.